# how to use a sentinel list in a comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list

```
In [4]: a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4]
```

from which I would like to remove duplicates via a comprehension using a sentinel list (see below why):

```
In [8]: [x if x not in seen else seen.append(x) for x in a]
Out[8]: [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4]
```

It seems that seen is not taken into account (neither updated, not checked). Why is it so?

As for the reason why using a convoluted method: The list I have is of the form

```
[{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 10, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 5}]
```

and I want to remove duplicates based on the value of a specific key (`b` in the case above, to leave `[{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 5}]` (I do not care which dict is removed). The idea would be to build a sentinel list with the values of `b` and keep only the dicts without `b` equal to any element in that sentinel list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `x` is not in `seen`, you are never adding it to `seen` either; the `else` branch is not executed when `x not in seen` is true.

However, you are using a conditional expression; it *always* produces a value; either `x` or the result of `seen.append()` (which is `None`), so you are not filtering, you are *mapping* here.

If you wanted to *filter*, move the test to an `if` section *after* the `for` loop:

```
seen = set()
[x for x in a if not (x in seen or seen.add(x))]
```

Since you were using `seen.append()` I presume you were using a list; I switched you to a `set()` instead, as membership tests are way faster using a set.

So `x` is *excluded* only if a) `x in seen` is true (so we have already seen it), or `seen.append(x)` returned a true value (`None` is not true). Yes, this works, if only a little convoluted.

Demo:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4]
>>> seen = set()
>>> [x for x in a if not (x in seen or seen.add(x))]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> seen
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Applying this to your specific problem:

```
>>> a = [{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 10, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 5}]
>>> seen = set()
>>> [entry for entry in a if not (entry['b'] in seen or seen.add(entry['b']))]
[{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 5}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You never execute the `else` part of the if, because you do not update when you match the first time. You could do this:

```
 [seen.append(x) or x for x in lst if x not in seen]
```

This way the `or` returns the last value (and executes the update using `append` (which always returns `None`, to let the or continue looking for truth-y value).

Maybe you can use the fact that `dict` keys are a set for this. If you want to prioritize the last items use `reversed` (last item is prioritized here):

```
>>> lst = [{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 10, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 5}]
>>> filtered = {item['b']: item for item in reversed(lst)}
>>> filtered.values()
[{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 5}]
```

This uses `'b'` as the key to map a value to, so only a single elemnt can be mapped to a value of '`b'`, which effectively creates a set over `'b'`.

**note:** this will return the values in random order. To fix it nicely, for big datasets, I'd create another mapping, of each object to it's index in the original list (O(n)), and use that mapping as a sorting function of the final result (O(n*log(n))). That's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Solution with dict is very nice. Much cleaner that exploiting side-effect of list comprehension.

Comment: @ArtemFedosov: yes, but it doesn't maintain the order.

Comment: @georg Empirically it does. I am not sure if python dict comprehension guarantees that, but looks like last key is always used. Same with defining a dict with duplicate keys. The author used reversed to make first element in the list appear the last.

Comment: @ArtemFedosov: the comprehension is fine, but `filtered.values()` returns stuff in a random order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always queasy making use of operator precedence as execution flow control.  I feel that the below is marginally more explicit and palatable, although it does carry the additional cost of tuple creation.

```
b_values = set()
[(item, b_values.add(item['b']))[0] for item in original_list
                                    if item['b'] not in b_values]
```

But really when you're maintaining/updating some sort of state, I think the best format is the simple for-loop:

```
output_list = []
b_values = set()
for item in original_list:
    if item['b'] not in b_values:
        output_list.append(item)
        b_values.add(item['b'])
```